# Why did a moderator uniterally remove from HNQ 'Why command hierarchy, if the chain of command is standing next to each other?'

Tags: discussion

[Why command hierarchy, if the chain of command is standing next to each other?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/54096/8309) has already been well answered. So I ask merely out of curiosity.

Comment: All moderator actions are "unilateral" by definition.

Answer (score 8):

The question, being about a YouTube video, is barely historical. It is also rather low effort, containing little in the way of preliminary research, nor attempts to tie the inquiry to a broader historical context, or even any intention to verify the historicity of a fictionalised portrayal. **In fact, a moderator raised concerns over the lack of research, but the OP appears to have ignored it.**

The net result is that the question is fundamentally one of the logic behind military practices, and a fictional portrayal thereof at that, rather than history. This is demonstrated also by the answers it received. Without intending any critique of their quality, most of the answers invoked logic or modern practices, rather than any application of historical methods.

For these reasons, this question is not particularly good fit on History.SE. While perhaps not to the point of putting the question on hold, it is nevertheless not desirable to feature it network wide.

Comment: You might infer that I agree from other posts. But for discussing the procedure: was that flagged in any way, flagged for HNQ-removal specifically, was there a mod-discussion about it, (in mod-cat / behind the scenes)… ?

Comment: @LangLangC No particular discussion in this case I'm afraid, since no one else was awake at the time. The question *had* been flagged for closure as being off-topic, which was declined. We may have to work out a procedure for more marginal cases, though I'd prefer to err on the side of inaction generally.